# probability of drawing 2 spades from a pack of cards given certain conditions

Tags: probability, card-games

I am studying maths as a hobby and have come across this problem:

2 cards are drawn simultaneously from a pack of 52. What is the probability that both are spades if one card in known to be a) black, b) red, c) a spade, d) a king?

I've tried a few approaches.

I worked out all the things I thought might be relevant.

e.g. Total ways of drawing 2 spades is $\binom {13}{2} = 78$, total ways of drawing black cards = $\binom {26}{2} = 325$, total ways of drawing *any* 2 cards = $\binom {52}{2} = 1326$ but I cannot find how to use these to get the answer.

Then I tried to reason as follows: in c), if we know the first card is a spade the probability of drawing another spade is $\frac {12}{52}$

but none of these approaches lead me to the correct answers.

Comment: You say "*if one card is known to be...*"  This is dangerous wording reminiscent of the boy-girl problem.  What do you mean by this?  *At least one* but it doesn't matter which?  *Exactly one*?  *The "First" one*?

Comment: Your attempted answer in (c) was following the idea that it was given that the "*first one*" was a spade, but you say this was wrong.  Indeed... if it was as I expect meant to be "*at least one (but not necessarily the first)*" then you got it wrong because you failed to consider what happens if it was the second one instead (*or alternately phrased, that you can't tell which was first or second*).

Comment: I strongly suggest looking at the standard interpretation of the boy-girl problem and then coming back to this and try to apply those techniques here.  In particular, note $\Pr(A\mid B) =\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$ and note that $\Pr(\text{At least one }X) = 1- \Pr(\text{None are }X)$

Comment: Can you recommend a source for the standard interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take $(c)$ for example,

The question says we know that one of the cards is a spade, what is the probability that both are spades? We need to apply conditional probability.

If Event $A$ is getting both as spades and Event $B$ is getting *at least* one spade in draw of $2$ cards then

i) $P(B) = \displaystyle \frac{{52 \choose 2} - {39 \choose 2}}{52 \choose 2} = \frac{15}{34}$

Numerator is number of ways to get *at least* one spade in a draw of $2$ cards, which is all possible draws of $2$ cards minus draws where none of the two cards is a spade.

ii) $ P(A\cap B) = \displaystyle \frac{{13 \choose 2}}{52 \choose 2} = \frac{1}{17}$

[please note that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)$]

So the desired probability $ \displaystyle P (A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{2}{15}$.

Now can you use this to evaluate others? If you get stuck, let me know.

While the above can be simplified a bit more, I have gone ahead and used standard working which is important to get used to for conditional probability.

Comment: I shall need to revise/learn about unions and intersections.  I understand your part i) but could you explain the part ii) formula - $P(A \cap B = \frac{\binom{13}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}})$ and why is $P(A \cap B)= P(A)$?

Comment: $A$ is set where both of them are spade. That is a subset of set $B$ which says _at least_ one spade. So the common cases in $A$ and $B$ is all of $A$. Let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.  It’s obviously something I need to study.  I may ask for further help.  Do I do that by putting a comment here?

Comment: Sure, feel free. If the comments become way too lengthy, it will ask us to take it to chat and we will do that at that point. Also were you able to complete other parts of the question? "given one card is black" is very similar. "given one card is king" will require a bit more of thinking. On your question on intersection, drawing Venn diagram may help.

Comment: I applied your method and it was successful, except when it came to the king part I got$\binom{4}{2}  \div   \frac{\binom{52}{2} - \binom{48}{ 2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$, which gives me 1/33 instead of the book's answer of 2/33.

Comment: And I must admit I am going very much by your "method", without intuitively understanding. More study on my part needed.

Comment: For king, think this way. $A \cap B$ means we should have at least a king and also both cards as spade. If I have both kings, I cannot have two spades. So possible cases that are common in both events are where you have king of spade and other card being one from rest of the $12$ spades. That is ${12} \choose 1$ ways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119909/discussion-between-steblo-and-math-lover).

Comment: yes I am fine. thanks.